# How do I change other mapping in AstroNVim?

Tags: neovim

So, today I just installed it and I'm loving it!

But, when I tried to make `K` work as `5k`, it didn't! Something else was going on when I pressed the key, so I opened `:WhichKey` and it showed me that `K` is bound to `Hover symbol details`. So, apparently AstroNvim binds extension keys after mine, so I have no way to rebind them to my needs. Or do I?

A similar problem happened when I tried to remap `L` to `]b`. But it didn't work. And if I'm right, it's because of the same reason - my bindings were loaded before AstroNVim's ones, so I couldn't bind them to `]b` as it wasn't bound at the point of loading my bindings. So I had to copy-paste the corresponding functions from `.../lua/astronvim/mappings.lua` to my `mappings.lua`.

How do I work with that and rebind `K` to `5k` and `Hover symbol details` to something else?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, I believe some of these mappings are added differently by AstroNvim. So the way to override them is also a bit different.

You can see the `K` mapping being defined in the file `~/.config/nvim/lua/astronvim/utils/lsp.lua`

```lua
M.on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
  [...]
  if capabilities.hoverProvider then
    lsp_mappings.n["K"] = {
      function() vim.lsp.buf.hover() end,
      desc = "Hover symbol details",
    }
  end
  [...]
end
```

Lower down in that document you'll find a hint as to how to be able to override these extra mappings:

```lua
  utils.set_mappings(user_opts("lsp.mappings", lsp_mappings), { buffer = bufnr })
```

So to be able to override this particular mapping, you will need to create a file named `~/.config/nvim/lua/user/lsp/mappings.lua`, with the following override:

```lua
return {
  n = { ["K"] = { "5k", desc = "Move up 5 lines" }, }
}
```

After restarting nvim, you should be able to use `K` for moving up 5 lines.